# Navigating and opening a Jupyter notebook outside of your directory tree from within JupyterLab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Is there an efficient way to open a notebook that is outside of the working directory tree? I can open a terminal in JupyterLab and cd to my desired location of course. How then do I open my desired notebook without starting another JupyterLab server? It seems like there should be a way to navigate using the left side, yet no. Or do I just need to use one of the plug-ins to save favorites? I feel like I must be missing something obvious.
Thanks